# Earthquake proof building

Tags: structural-engineering

If a building or big structure is situated on top of flat ground without any of its part inside the ground, should the building be safe? Let's say our building is a big (as big as we can imagine) rubic's cube made with mordern day building materials.

Comment: Nature can destroy huge amounts of land and has almost infinite time to do so.

Comment: @SolarMike Let's just say the ground  beneath won't disappear.

Comment: But it can split, move or change level...

Comment: @SolarMike Let's also assume that it won't be enough to make the cube shape structure roll over.

Comment: It totally depends on the design and the implementation of it. If you apply enough material in a sensible way you can make the building stiff enough to make it reasonably safe. 'Reasonably' because we can only estimate the probability that a certain groundwave strength will occur. Acceleration, speed, waveform, duration, frequency, amplitude, all play a roll.

Comment: Welcome to Engineering! This looks like a ['Naive design' question](http://meta.engineering.stackexchange.com/q/188/1832). Such questions are excessively broad and are therefore not a good fit for our format. See if you can [edit] your question to make it specific and answerable.

Answer (score 1):

Even if a building is just sitting on the ground which is not acceptable for many reasons, it needs to be designed for horizontal, P wave, and vertical, S wave, vibrations of the ground.

The friction between concrete and compact soil is between 0.60 and 0.40 depending on the type of soil. So a 4 story structure with an estimate of 3000kg weight per square meter will experience approximately 1500kg per square meter lateral force during an earthquake.

Assuming the foundation of the building is concrete the forces of the earthquake can transfer by shaking of the ground to the foundation. Then the foundation will move laterally with the ground, while the inertia of the floors above will hold them back, causing the structure to vibrate and undergo large stresses due to moment and shear which may eventually lead to distruction of the building.

There is also vertical earthquake wave, S wave, these can break the structure same way a ship caught in cross waves break apart. The building designer has to consider that.